# how to confirm the reason of high load of system?

Tags: java, load, system

I'm deploy my java application in a centos server , the system load in 5 increase to 3 suddenly,i have make sure there is no full gc ,and io is normal,one thing special is that i have increase the number of thread to 100 ,but all of them are WAITING,is there any possible way for me to find the reason of high load?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a profiler to have an idea on your application behavior. please have a look at :

- https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html
- https://visualvm.github.io/
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/intro.html